# Creating a form builder, how to implement the backend PHP Laravel MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to get create a system for users to be able to create questionnaires, all the ways I envision this are cumbersome to create and don't seems to be efficient.

When the user specifics:

1. One txt field.
2. One multiple choose ( String, String, String )
3. etc

How would I save this data to the database in an efficient way. Is there any tutorials on anything like this?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What schema are you proposing here? Concrete examples are a lot easier to speak to.

Comment: Im not, Currently i have one static questionnaire a user can use, all the entries are held in that static table, but now i would like the users to be able to create their own questionnaires. Should I create a new table for each questionnaires if it doesn't match an existing table? Whats it the best way to approach this at the MYSQL end? Should I have a table for each input type IE Varchar then a table for the questionnaire that references the type tables? Etc I have not idea at the right way to be this so would just like to hear some experiences from others.

Comment: The way this works best is if you pitch something, anything, and people can speak to its strengths or weaknesses. Right now you're speaking in super broad terms. Those things might work. It really depends on how you're putting it together.

Answer (score 0):

[This laravel 5 example](https://github.com/westhacker/laravel-api) should be your best choice. Create your questionnaire app based on this example should be very easy.